# Ckeditor bullets and numberedlists are not displaying in result

Tags: ckeditor

I have applied ckeditor on a textarea . it display bold and italic txext as it is but does not display numbered lists and bulletlist in results when i fetch from database. Instaead it encapsulte whole text in ol/ul tags.

  A
  **secretary**
  ,
  **personal assistant**
  , or
  **administrative assistant**
  is a person whose work consists of supporting management, including executives, using a variety of project management,
  communication, or organizational skills. These functions may be entirely carried out to assist one other employee or may be for the benefit of
  more than one. In other situations a secretary is an officer of a society or organization
  who deals with correspondence, admits new members, and organizes official meetings and events

Jquery code to apply ckeditor:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Applying ckeditor on provider msg textarea.
CKEDITOR.replace( 'responsibilities', 
    {
    uiColor: '#6C518F',
    toolbar: [
                { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','TextColor',"BGColor", 'NumberedList','BulletedList'  ] },
                { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize','-' ] }
            ],
    removePlugins : 'elementspath'
});
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's caused most likely by:

- Either some backend filtering which strips lists.
- Or styling of your webpage, which sets `list-style-type` to `none`.

If none of these is true, please clarify your question.

Comment: I have applied strip tag function.

Comment: In which class i can set the list-style-type: none in ckeditors?

Answer (score 5):

I also faced same issue while using ckeditor in Angular. When we fetch the data from the editor it shows with ul/li tag. Actually it is applying the bulleted list to the editor but it is not visible to us. So we just need to increase the padding so that it can be visible to us.

```
.ck-editor__editable_inline {
    padding: 0 30px !important;
}
```

Comment: You need to add ::ng-deep pseudo-class to make it work properly: ::ng-deep .ck-editor__editable_inline

Answer (score 0):

Removing `list-style-type to none` resolved my issues.